# Как можно сократить код слишком длинный?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

```py
def isdigit1(a):
    n_list = list(a)
    count = 0
    for s in n_list:
        if s.isdigit() == True:
            count += 1
    if count >= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False   

def isalpha1(a):
    n_list = list(a)
    count = 0
    for s in n_list:
        if s.isalpha() == True:
            count += 1
    if count > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def islower1(a):
    n_list = list(a)
    count = 0
    for s in n_list:
        if s.islower() == True:
            count += 1
    if count >= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def isupper1(a):
    n_list = list(a)
    count = 0
    for s in n_list:
        if s.isupper() == True:
            count += 1
    if count >= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    print(s.isalnum())
    print(isalpha1(s))
    print(isdigit1(s))
    print(islower1(s))
    print(isupper1(s))
```

ругается валидатор проверки решения, для более ресурсоемких тестов

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def isdigit1(a):
    n_list = list(a) # Преобразовывать строку в список не надо - цикл
                     # перебирает символы строки так же как элементы списка.

    count = 0
    for s in n_list:
        if s.isdigit() == True: # `== True` почти всегда бесполезен
            count += 1

    # if ...: return True; else: return False можно сократить до
    # return ...
    if count >= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

- 

```
def isdigit1(a):
    count = 0
    for s in a:
        if s.isdigit():
            count += 1 # зачем считать, достаточно одного раза
    return count >= 1
```

- 

```
def isdigit1(a):
    for s in a:
        if s.isdigit(): # для подобных проверок есть any
            return True
    return False
```

- 

```
def isdigit1(a):
    return any(s.isdigit() for s in a)
```

Теперь видна ошибка: `isdigit1` проверяет что в строке **есть** цифры. А нужно проверять что в строке **все** цифры:

```
def isdigit1(a):
    return len(s) > 0 and all(s.isdigit() for s in a)
```

Но встроенная `str.isdigit` уже это делает:

```
def isdigit1(a):
    return a.isdigit()
```

**P.S.** На правах шутки. `a.isdigit()` можно записать как `str.isdigit(a)`. Функция которая вызывает другую и ничего больше не делает может быть записана как:

```
isdigit1 = str.isdigit
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def isdigit1(a):
    return any(s.isdigit() for s in a)
```

С остальными аналогично

Answer (score 2):

Несколько замечаний на примере первой функции.

1. Нет необходимости преобразовывать с типу данных `list`, можно перебирать по символу в строке
2. Нет необходимости накапливать значение в счетчик, поскольку вам необходимо только одно совпадение, чтобы вернуть `True`
3. Нет необходимости писать `if s.isdigit() == True:`, поскльку под капотом это выглядит вот так `if True == True`. Пишите просто `if s.isdigit():`
4. Нет необходимости пробегать по всем значениям последовательности, можно вернуть `True` при первом попадании.

из всего вышесказанного

```py
def isdigit1(a):
    for s in a:
        if s.isdigit():
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

еще короче код ;)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
s = input()
print(any(c.isalnum() for c in s))
print(any(c.isalpha() for c in s))
print(any(c.isdigit() for c in s))
print(any(c.islower() for c in s))
print(any(c.isupper() for c in s))
```